# What is the technology called "Streaming channels" on Android TV

Tags: android-tv, sony

I have a Sony Android TV (Android 7) which have several categories of channels: TV channels, input channels (HDMI etc) and streaming channels. By default there is only Google Play Movies channel in that category which worked until recently showing random movies ADs.

What is the technology behind this "Streaming channels"? Is there other of this type? Is it an application should be installed adding itself to that category? Is there any solution I can use or create for my own streaming, like from Linux to TV?